# Wifi dosn't work after waking up. Thinkpad X60

Tags: wireless, suspend, thinkpad, iwlwifi

Sometimes, wifi won't be able to reconnect after waking up from sleep. I remember having similar issues with Windows too. I searched and found this post: http://justaddwater.dk/2007/07/25/lenov ... r-standby/. It suggests turning off "Deep Smart Power Down" in Windows. Does anyone know what's the equivalent in Linux? Thanks.

When I lose the wifi (which I do half of the time when waking up), I can do a rmmod and modprobe to bring it back.

The wifi card is Intel 3945ABG:

```
delingren@x60:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
```

Comment: Let's be certain. Please run and post, from the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Here it is:

delingren@x60:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
 Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
delingren@x60:~$

Answer (score 0):

This technique sometimes, but not always works. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add one line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwl3945"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Comment: Nope :(. However, when I lose wifi, if I do a rmmod and modprobe, I can get it back without rebooting.

Comment: That suggestion is not to "get it back" but to fix the whole problem.